Sum of Exponential and Erlang random variables
Let $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, and $Y\sim \text{Erlang}(k,\gamma)$ be two independent random variables. Is it possible to write a closed formula for $P(X+Y>t)$?
My attempt: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, their sum $X + Y$ has a distribution that is the convolution of their individual distributions. We can use the Laplace transform of the sum of independent random variables. The Laplace transform of the sum $X + Y$ is the product of the Laplace transforms of $X$ and $Y$.
The Laplace transform of $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ is:
$$
   \mathcal{L}_X(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \frac{\lambda}{s + \lambda}.
   $$
The Laplace transform of $Y \sim \text{Erlang}(k, \gamma)$ is:
$$
   \mathcal{L}_Y(s) = \left( \frac{\gamma}{s + \gamma} \right)^k.
   $$
Thus, the Laplace transform of $X + Y$ is:
$$
\mathcal{L}_{X + Y}(s) = \frac{\lambda}{s + \lambda} \cdot \left( \frac{\gamma}{s + \gamma} \right)^k.
$$
To obtain $P(X + Y > t)$, we would need to invert this Laplace transform, but this seems hard. Any ideas?
Note: We naturally have $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{k}{\gamma}$, but I am interested in the expression for $P(X+Y>t)$, as motivated by the following, more general, problem.
Motivation and context: For $X_i\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $Y_i\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\text{Erlang}(|i|,\gamma)$, and $X_i \perp Y_i,\forall i$, I want to determine the expected value of the following random variable
$$
Z=\min_i\{X_i+Y_i\}
$$
for $-n\leq i\leq n$. By definition and due to independence, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z]=\int_0^\infty P(\min_i\{X_i+Y_i\}>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty \prod_i P(X_i+Y_i>t)\,dt.
$$
Any idea how to expand this?

$\mathcal{L}{X + Y}(-s)$ is precisely the moment-generating function of $X+Y$, so that $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = -\mathcal{L}{X + Y}'(0)$.

@Abezhiko Thanks! I guess, ultimately, we also have $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{k}{\gamma}$, but I am looking for an expression for $P(X+Y>t)$. Perhaps I should have phrased the question differently. Please see the edited question to see the broader context behind this question.
